# Android Wifi with same name

Tags: wi-fi, stock-android

I want to know if i add wifi network with say ssid="test" can i anyway add same ssid="test" with different configurations like ip and gateways?

EDIT :

Suppose wifi has been configured with below configuration :[Added manually]

```
SSID : "Test"
Security : None 
and No Any advance settings provided.
```

Now can i add another wifi with settings below :

```
SSID : "Test"
Security : WEP 
and No Any advance settings provided.
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add a little more detail about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @DanHulme edited

Comment: @DanHulme any clue for answer?

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Do you already have two Wi-Fi networks with the same SSID, and you want to know if you can add settings for both of them? Or is there one Wi-Fi network, and you want to connect to it with two different sets of settings? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Adding  any number of duplicate SSID's is possible if you have a unique IP address.

In lay man's terms SSID is nothing but just an identification given to that particular network given to distinguish that network from others for simplicity. What defines that network is it's IP Address.If you have a conflict between an IP address then it may be a real problem.

For some devices(like Samsung) you need to check the to Display open Network connection if available in order to view open connections and for some devices it shows by default.

Ex:-Let's say you have two network's with SSID as Test.
Test1 has an open connection available for public use and Test2 is for personal use and is encrypted. Your mobile device will simply connect to a network whose signal strength is good. As the IP address is different there will not be any conflict and you can do your browsing.

In case there's any  conflict(same signal strength) then the device will ask the user to select the desired network or search for a new network.

**Caution:-Browsing an open network for reasons related to finance leads to severe security threats browse at your own risk.**

An IP address serves two principal functions: host or network interface identification and location addressing. Its role has been characterized as follows: "A name indicates what we seek. An address indicates where it is. A route indicates how to get there.

The most simple definition for IP Address I could give is-

IP address act as you house address to which the shipment has to be delivered.If you have two same addresses then to whom will the shipment be delivered.
For further details about IP [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address)

Comment: but android let me add with different ssid id and same ip with no issue... basically i just wanna understand whats unque factory to add extacly duplicate wifi settings

Comment: @DIVA I had two SSID's with same I.P addresses(old and new SSID) but later caused me a problem because my device was not clear about which I.P to use. So I had to forget the old SSID. Android will allow but the networking protocols may not

Comment: how do i test this in real time?

Comment: You need to get two WI-FI's network around you with the same ISP provider. As ISP's generally have same SSID for many customer's like the popular D-Link. Save both the SSID's and check their IP  addresses. The open and the closed might have different IP's although they have the same Name .For more details check on the IP address and it's limitations with the duplicates in google or other Stack site.

Comment: ok but i dont thing it can ever happen that ssid id can be same and rest say ip and all r different...i tried to add same ssid with different configs butnever works

Comment: It happens for the DLink or the UT-Starcom kind of modem's wherein the customer's don't change their SSID (modify the default SSID which comes when installed to the custom names) and it's not a good practice.

Comment: but m talking abt android device wifi :(

Comment: U didn't get me dear @div it's in the Android device. The android device will detect network's based on the SSID the modem's broadcast.

Comment: ohh ok, are you sure ip is the atleast unquie factor betteen networks?

Comment: kindly view the answer updated

Comment: @Div It's the easiest definition I could provide

Comment: ok let me back with some more questions